# Is there a way to inherit iterator stuff

Tags: c++, inheritance

This is a template for a container with a limit on its size.

```
template <class T, int MAXSIZE>
class svector {

class iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, value_type> {
public:
    iterator( T* cptr );
    iterator( const iterator& mit);
    bool operator==(const iterator& rhs) const;
    bool operator!=(const iterator& rhs) const;
    T operator*();
    iterator& operator++();
    iterator operator++(int);

protected:
    T* eleptr;
};

svector();
svector( const svector& vec);
virtual ~svector();
svector& operator=( const svector& rhs );
iterator begin();
iterator end();

// more
};
```

As you can see, an iterator is there as well, subclassing std::iterator.
However, you can't inherit anything from this "marker" class, and I have
bravely implemented all you can see up here. Is there a way of inheriting
stuff from somewhere in the STL?

Comment: The short answer is: No.

Comment: No, you can't inherit *functionality*, because that's going to differ for each container you build.

Comment: typedef T* iterator and your are done

Comment: If you're after an easy iterator implementation that differs from an existing iterator, try `boost::iterator_facade` or `boost::iterator_adapter`.

Comment: @DieterLücking Are you sure? I didn't leak that the Ts are in a T[]? (Although that's an educated guess ;-) )

Comment: @chris Sorry, boost is off-limits.

Comment: @BrianBi Yes, stands to reason, but there might be some "vanilla" implementation from which you can boilerplate your stuff - see what Dieter was referring to?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ And the long one? ;-)

Comment: @laune Would result in the same, statement ;)! _see what Dieter was referring to?_ He was just referring to the fact, an iterator has the same behavior as it would be a pointer to the contained element type of a container.

Answer (score 1):

Not for "stuff" in general, but for iterators there are [`boost::iterator_facade` and `boost::iterator_adapter`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/index.html#iterator-facade-and-adaptor). The former makes it easier to write an iterator from scratch, the latter is handy for building on an existing iterator.